# Are there Java classes for Camunda Rest responses?

Tags: json, spring, rest, camunda, spring-webclient

Im currently trying to set up REST calls from Spring to my local camunda instance using the camunda rest api.

Here's how i've set it up:

1. Started a local camunda docker container on my `localhost:8080` like this: https://hub.docker.com/r/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform
   (i've tested calls with postman and they are working)
2. Built a maven project using a couple of camunda and rest dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. Wrote a simple service to make rest calls from Spring (taken from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webclient):

```java
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class MyExampleService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MyExampleService (WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();
    }

    @Override
    public ProcessDefinitionEntity[] getCamundaProcesses() {

        ProcessDefinitionEntity[] myResponse = this.webClient.get().uri("/engine-rest/process-definition/")
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                    System.out.println("4xx eror");
                    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("4xx"));
                })
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
                    System.out.println("5xx eror");
                    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("5xx"));
                })
                .bodyToMono(ProcessDefinitionEntity[].class)
                .block();

        return myResponse;
}
```

So I basically used Spring WebClient to make a rest call to `localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/` which should give me a list of all processes as JSON (according to https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/deployment/get-query/).

Now when I convert the response directly into a ProcessDefinitionEntity[] it won't cast the JSON into it. I also tried other classes from the camunda Java API (https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.11/) like `ProcessDefinitionDto`.

None of the classes seem to properly fit the response I get from camunda. The response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "invoice:1:cdbc3f02-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "key": "invoice",
        "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Invoice Receipt",
        "version": 1,
        "resource": "invoice.v1.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "cda115de-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": "V1.0",
        "historyTimeToLive": 30,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    },
    {
        "id": "invoice:2:ce03f66c-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "key": "invoice",
        "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Invoice Receipt",
        "version": 2,
        "resource": "invoice.v2.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "cdfbb908-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": "V2.0",
        "historyTimeToLive": 45,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    }
]
```

(which are just the two standard processes that are in the docker container)

**Are there classes in the camunda java api that properly match the responses from the camunda rest api?**

PS:
The ProcessDefinitionDto that i got from the maven dependency (which lies in `package org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.repository.ProcessDefinitionDto`) looks like this:

```java
public class ProcessDefinitionDto {
    protected String id;
    protected String key;
    protected String category;
    protected String description;
    protected String name;
    protected int version;
    protected String resource;
    protected String deploymentId;
    protected String diagram;
    protected boolean suspended;
    protected String tenantId;
    protected String versionTag;
    protected Integer historyTimeToLive;
    protected boolean isStartableInTasklist;
...
```

And the Response that I get from my postman call to `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "b506eb34-e6b1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "key": "example_workflow",
        "category": "http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Just an Example",
        "version": 1,
        "resource": "example_workflow.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "b503b6e2-e6b1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": null,
        "historyTimeToLive": null,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    },
    {
        "id": "invoice:1:cdbc3f02-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "key": "invoice",
        "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Invoice Receipt",
        "version": 1,
        "resource": "invoice.v1.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "cda115de-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": "V1.0",
        "historyTimeToLive": 30,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    },
    {
        "id": "invoice:2:ce03f66c-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "key": "invoice",
        "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Invoice Receipt",
        "version": 2,
        "resource": "invoice.v2.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "cdfbb908-e6a1-11e9-8de8-0242ac110002",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": "V2.0",
        "historyTimeToLive": 45,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes in

> org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.runtime

are suitable. (https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tree/master/engine-rest/engine-rest/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/rest/dto)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-engine-rest-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your case it would be **ProcessDefinitionDto**
Usage Example with Spring REST template:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RuntimeServiceImpl implements RuntimeService {

    private final RestTemplate rest;
    @Value("${camunda.server.rest.url}")
    private String restURL;

    public RuntimeServiceImpl(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        this.rest = builder.build();
    }

    public ProcessDefinitionDto[] getProcessDefinitions() {

        ResponseEntity<ProcessDefinitionDto[]> response = rest.getForEntity(restURL + "process-definition/",
                ProcessDefinitionDto[].class);
        ProcessDefinitionDto[] processes = response.getBody();

        Arrays.stream(processes).forEach(pd -> log.info("Found process definition {} with id {} and key {}", pd.getName(), pd.getId(), pd.getKey()));

        return processes;
    }
}
```

Complete client project: https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-rest-client

The [external class client](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java) contains further interfaces and DTOs which you could reuse, such as

> org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.dto.FetchAndLockRequestDto;
>   org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.dto.TopicRequestDto;

Or just use / fork the complete client project. A lot work was already done for you there.

P.s. following comment:
The response includes an array of process definitions with these fields:

```
[
    {
        "id": "AccountOpening:1:a6f88770-0ae7-11ea-9ef3-00155d00d800",
        "key": "AccountOpening",
        "category": "http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn",
        "description": null,
        "name": "Account Opening",
        "version": 1,
        "resource": "C:\\account-opening\\target\\classes\\bpmn\\AccountOpening.bpmn",
        "deploymentId": "a6cc4747-0ae7-11ea-9ef3-00155d00d800",
        "diagram": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "tenantId": null,
        "versionTag": null,
        "historyTimeToLive": null,
        "startableInTasklist": true
    }
```

The target data structure in package **org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.repository** contains the same fields:

```
public class ProcessDefinitionDto {
    protected String id;
    protected String key;
    protected String category;
    protected String description;
    protected String name;
    protected int version;
    protected String resource;
    protected String deploymentId;
    protected String diagram;
    protected boolean suspended;
    protected String tenantId;
    protected String versionTag;
    protected Integer historyTimeToLive;
    protected boolean isStartableInTasklist;
   ...}
```

If the deserialization fails then ensure you are using the correct package (not for instance org.camunda.bpm.cockpit.impl.plugin.base.dto)

Comment: When I make the GET call to `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/` the result does not work with the Java class `List<ProcessInstanceWithVariablesDto>`

Comment: I updated my answer to your specific case and added an example client project on GitHub

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I was busy doing other parts of my application.

So I copied and tried the solution from your RuntimeServiceImpl class. However this doesn't seem to work:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcdfe8dgj44fiay/camundaProcessDefinition.png?dl=0)

I am getting 3 results (which is correct because I have 3 Processes in my local camunda instance) But they are not casted correctly into the ProcessDefinitionDto array :(

Comment: If you use the right query then the deserialization should work. Any chance you can share your code, e.g. via github?

Comment: I can't share my whole project (because of copyright issues), but I made a folder containing all relevant files for my problem: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m4yv8zi0gjae7rl/AACG64ViKkK-_vDT7SDoLQAZa?dl=0) as you can see my service literally only does this simple call to the rest api of camunda. I also have commented out code which actually workes. There I made a custom ProcessDefinition class and casted the JSON response into it, that DID work (but is a hacky solution imho)

Comment: So I was also reading through the External Class Client which is basically a wrapper for the rest api (according to [this](https://forum.camunda.org/t/external-task-as-rest-apis/13281/3)). However there is no example how to get the list of process-definitions using that wrapper-library. [ExternalTaskClientBuilder.java](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-java/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/client/ExternalTaskClientBuilder.java) also doesn't contain anything close to process-definitions.

Comment: Please see the P.S. I added to the answer. Are you using the correct package? Your code looks like you do. Have you tried to checkout and run my spring boot project against your server? Same issue? I believe the client environments could differ with regards to the Jackson configuration.

Comment: I added a PS to my question containing the Information that you asked for. The package for my `ProcessDefinitionDto` is correct. I will try to fork your project tomorrow and see if that works.

Comment: Ok so I cloned your client project and it indeed works! That probably means that my own project has other dependencies that mess with the parsing. I will try out different JDKs and try to uncomment my other dependencies to find the cause of that issue. Anyways, that means your answer solves my Issue!

Comment: I found the problem, I had to set the jackson serialization to the default for some reason:
`this.rest = builder.defaultMessageConverters().build();`

Comment: Good to know and glad it is working now. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the correct package? There are multiple ProcessDefinitionDto classes in Camunda codebase. 
The one you're looking for is in the package `org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.repository` in camunda-engine-rest-core.jar

The class looks like this, which exactly matches your output:

```
package org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.repository;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.repository.ProcessDefinition;

public class ProcessDefinitionDto {

  protected String id;
  protected String key;
  protected String category;
  protected String description;
  protected String name;
  protected int version;
  protected String resource;
  protected String deploymentId;
  protected String diagram;
  protected boolean suspended;
  protected String tenantId;
  protected String versionTag;
  protected Integer historyTimeToLive;
  protected boolean isStartableInTasklist;

  ...
```

Comment: this class doesn't exactly fit my json response. the response has `startableInTasklist` while this class calls it `isStartableInTasklist`

Comment: That's just a naming convention. If you check the sources for the rest interface(`ProcessDefinitionRestServiceImpl.java` in camunda-engine-rest-core) package, you'll see that's the correct class being used. Jax-ws will convert this property to startableInTasklist in rest response.